# I use fullcalendar to make the event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I use fullcalendar to make the event , but there is a problem like this:

> fullcalendar.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'stripTime' of undefined

js

```js
var a ='<?php echo $class_id?>'  
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('#event').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            allDayDefault: true,
            editable: false,
            events: {
                url: "events/" + a ,
            },
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more context? What events are being included. Most likely the start or end properties of the event is not setup properly which would be why you're getting this error.